# 2 DNS Entries, Multiple Servers

Tags: domain-name-system

At the moment we have:

```
ns1.example.com -> dns1
ns2.example.com -> dns2
```

I was wondering if it was possible to do something like this:

```
ns1.example.com -> dns1, dns3, dns5
ns2.example.com -> dns2, dns4, dns6
```

I am attempting to set up a round robin, fault resistant setup with as little hops as possible.

Comment: You need to add more information.  Are you trying to do round robin dns? Are you trying to load balance DNS-servers? Etc.

Comment: More information has been added.

Comment: RFC2182, section 4.3: When a server is [...] using different addresses, that server should be given two names,each name associated with appropriate A records, [...] This should then be treated just like two servers [...]. (They don't provide any reasons for it though.)

Answer (score 2):

DNS is redundant by design.

Adding what you think is additional redundancy doesn't actually help.

Comment: Yes, but not only do I want the redundancy, I also want to have fast turn over times for DNS setups.

Comment: Which  simply can not be done - this is a client decision and the specs do not give that. Point.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible to do this:

```
ns1.example.com -> dns1, dns3, dns5
ns2.example.com -> dns2, dns4, dns6
```

by having multiple `A` records for each of `ns1` and `ns2`.

However you might as well do this:

```
ns1.example.com. IN A ...
   ...
ns6.example.com. IN A ...
```

which should give you more even distribution of queries across the six servers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add more name servers just add more NS records.  They will be served up in a round robin fashion by default.  Unless you have lots of traffic two or three name servers should be sufficient.  Most requests will be served from cache if you have much traffic.

If you have the kind of traffic that Google, Amazon, or Facebook have you should have technical staff who know how to optimize DNS for fast server access.

Comment: Actually google does not optimize DNS - they use special IP address ing that is easy to implement IF (!) you have your own address space (AS, BGP routing) and jsut route it to multiple locations.

Comment: @TomTom:  The addresses they return are constantly changing and are different depending where you connect from.  I consider that optimization.  It isn't the only arrow in their quiver though.